# How to define and declare a struct when the constructor is used for a default argument?

Tags: c++, struct, header, declaration

I have a .h file inside I have a function that uses a Struct/Class Constructor for the default argument.

It appears on the declaration end like answered here : [Where to put default parameter value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c/4989591)

Function declaration

```
vector<UINT_PTR> scan(const ScanOptions& scan_options = ScanOptions());
```

Struct definition

```
struct ScanOptions {

ScanOptions()
{
    //Use some Windows.h functions here to find values
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    start_address = sysinfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    end_address = sysinfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

}

UINT_PTR start_address;
UINT_PTR end_address;
};
```

It is answered here that:

> Private structures for that file should go in the .c file, with a declaration in the .h file if they are used by any functions in the .h .

[Should struct definitions go in .h or .c file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316987/should-struct-definitions-go-in-h-or-c-file)

There doesnt seem to be a way to declare a struct only to forward declare it?

[C++, how to declare a struct in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732978/c-how-to-declare-a-struct-in-a-header-file)

So do I just keep the declaration and definition of my struct inside my header or is there another recommended way?

I mean I dont really care that its global since its working and I dont think its gonna lead to problems but I really wanna know.

Comment: I *think* this is what you're asking about. [Use function returning incomplete type as default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139207/use-function-returning-incomplete-type-as-default-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
vector<UINT_PTR> scan(const ScanOptions& scan_options = ScanOptions());
```

in the .h file, then the definition of `ScanOptions` must be visible at the point of declaration of the function.

However, instead of using a default argument, you can overload the function.

```
vector<UINT_PTR> scan();
vector<UINT_PTR> scan(const ScanOptions& scan_options);
```

with the understanding that the first function will use a default constructed `ScanOptions` to do its job. With that change, you can forward declare `ScanOptions` in the .h file and define it only in the .cpp file.

The following is perfectly valid and does not require the definition of `ScanOptions` to be in the .h file.

```
struct ScanOptions;

vector<UINT_PTR> scan();
vector<UINT_PTR> scan(const ScanOptions& scan_options);
```

Comment: Ohhh ofcourse just overloading thanks so much, I feel stupid now

Comment: @Ojav, No need to feel bad. It's part of the journey. You learn the tricks of the trade along the way.